# Web application not responding on IIS 10 after OS Upgrade

Tags: iis, .net, windows-server-2022, angular

I upgraded to Windows 2022 and IIS 10 from Windows 2016 and IIS 8. But after the upgrade my 2 sites are badly affected. In the evening, when the traffic on the server increases, it goes into non-responsive mode. I'm not able to find anything in event viewer and logs. When I recycle the application pool it responsive again. Please guide me how can I fix this issue.

- Application 1 frontend based on: Angular 6
- Application 1 webservice based on: .Net Framework 4.5.1
- Application 2 webservice based on: .Net Framework 4.6.1 (This application consumes Apache solr that is already deployed on another server)

Comment: Both of those.NET versions no longer exist, and were replaced years ago. What other information do you have? How are you measuring and monitoring performance?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/

Comment: I would start a performance log perfmon and let that run and analyze it. Of course include the iis counters

Comment: Any customisations made to IIS for your sites? For instance within `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`? Noticed recently, unlike 20212 R2 > 2016 or 2016 > 2019, updating to 2022 resets at least some of that including any custom permissions.

Comment: In many cases, the actual OS upgrade contributed to such problems, not necessarily .NET Framework or IIS. Please use a performance profiler or hang dump analysis to determine what might be wrong and start from there. You can open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com if you need further assistance.